# Changing the priority of Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, system

I want to give Gnome-Shell the highest priority, but I couldn't change the priority on the System Monitor, an error messeage says: **Can't change priority's process with pid 2841 to -5. Access denied**

I tried the following commands:

```
gksu gnome-system-monitor
```

But I can't find Gnome-Shell on the processes list, so I tried "renice command", like this:

```
sudo renice -15 2841
```

And finally got this problem, the Gnome-Shell's PID always changes, it's not the same PID numbers, so I have to change the priority every time I start up my system.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to reassign Gnome-Shell priority process?! The system manages just fine on its own, or is there any particular reason?!

Comment: I want to do that because ATI Driver is not fully compatible and sometimes Gnome Shell disappears for a few seconds then returns back, and some other time it disappears and suddenly falls back to classic mode without panels, so I have to hit ctrl+alt+del to logout and login back again, not to mention that some times the ctrl+alt+del method doesn't work and find myself with no option but power off my laptop and turn it on again.

Comment: Playing with the priority of processes will not help - your problem is with your graphics driver & your graphics card.  What driver are you using?  what graphics card (lspci | grep VGA) and what version of ubuntu?  Remember - edit all responses back into your question.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 x64 and my graphic driver is ATI, changing the priority somehow helps a little bit, I want to change it until ATI fixes all GNOME 3 problems, that if they did anyway...

Comment: You just keep asking me why do I need to change the priority, just tell me how to do it, that will be more helpful than answering me with questions.

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree with your commenters that this is not a good idea and not likely to help, and I can't really recommend it, but here goes:

`renice -15 -p $(pgrep gnome-shell)`

This will figure out the PID of gnome-shell and change the priority.  You would need to run the command as root and place it in a cron job so that it would automatically renice all processes with that name.